# grails: scaffolding create view for domain with hasMany relation

Tags: grails, gsp, scaffolding

Let's assume the following (simplified) domain classes:

```
class Person {

    static hasMany = [stringProperties: StringProperty]

    static constraints = {
    }

}
```

and

```
class StringProperty {

    String name
    String value

    static constraints = {
        name blank:false
        value blank: true
    }

}
```

When scaffolding generates the create view, there is no option in the gsp to create a StringProperty from Person.

Does a plugin exist or does somebody know a best practice, that can render a sort of create ui that allows to create members of a hasmany relation.

I'm just asking before i take the time to modify the scaffolding templates.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the areas where a plugin or enhanced scaffolding would be welcomed by the community. If I had the time I would take the information [presented here](http://omarello.com/2010/08/grails-one-to-many-dynamic-forms/) and make a plugin for it. I have used this approach a few times and it works well.